# No suitable application records were found and no way to get Waiting for Upload status

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to validate and submit my app but got:

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier '*****.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)' is correct.

I searched for a few hours and found other people having same problems but none of the solutions apply to my case:

1. There IS an app created in iTunes connect and I made sure the bundle ID in the project settings matches the one used in iTunesConnect
2. Some said the status has to be Waiting for Upload while my status is Prepare for Submission, but there is no 'Ready to Upload' or '+' button anyone on the app's page, I triple checked all the fields and made sure all non-optional fields are filled in but still there is no way to change the status to waiting for submission

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes Connect was updated some time back and doesn't say *Waiting For Upload* any more. Now it is *Prepare for Submission*
As to why you may not upload it, I am not one hundred percent sure, but I will outline a few steps down below:

1) Check that your Bundle ID is one to one the same. You can't have spaces and it's case sensitive

2) Try to upload your app rather then just verifying it. I have sometimes had a similar issue while validating, ad just uploading it changed it without a problem.

3) Check if you have the latest version of Xcode, if not try to update.

4) Lastly, try restarting Xcode. That may help

Not one of my initial points, but double check that you're uploading to the correct account.

Hope that helps,
Julian

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did make sure: 1. bundle ID is correct 2. I tried both the App Uploader and in XCode, but all getting the same issue 3. XCode is latest 4. Tried as well as removing all the module caches / derived data.

Comment: Hm. That's really weird. My last suggestion would be to delete the app record and try to start over. If that doesn't work you can always contact iTunes connect support. Let me know, if it doesn't work out, I'll get you their email from the WWDC.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I thought about deleting it but I couldn't, the app has to be either published or in one of the eligible statuses to be removed, I did contact support and they asked me to provide all the details which I did, hopefully they can sort it out, thanks again!

Comment: You can email them at: itunesconnect@apple.com. If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @julian-e, the issue is exactly what you said, the bundle ID was changed at some stage but I forgot :-(